# Solving Heat equation using python

Tags: python, plot, physics, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the heat equation and then plot a graph like this one:[image]

[image: Here is the heat equation i am trying to solve]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 0.04     # soil depth
Te = 28    # ext tempe
Tn = 36.6      # tempe at x = L
D = 0.75    #  m2.s-1
tau = 232920  # total lengh of experiment
dt = 600   
dx = 0.001  
Tm=38   #average temperature
T=24*3600 #period
w=(2*pi)/T

Nt = int(tau/dt)+1  
Nx = int(L/dx)+1    

x = [j*dt for j in range(Nx)]       
T = np.zeros((Nt,Nx))               
for j in range(Nx):
    T[0,j] = Te    # T(x,t=0) = Te
T[0,0] = Te         # T(x=0,t=0) = Te
for i in range(1,Nt): 
    T[i,0] = Te+Tm*np.cos(w*i)     # T(x=0,t) = ...
    T[i,-1] = Tn    # T(x=L,t) = Tn 


for i in range(Nt-1):   
    for j in range(1,Nx-1):    
        T[i+1,j]=T[i,j]+D*dt/(dx*dx)*(T[i,j+1]+T[i,j-1]-2*T[i,j])

t=np.arange(0, 232920, 10*60)
plt.plot(t, T[i,:], label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (c)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

So far i have managed using the solution of the heat equation to plot the graph using this code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *


t0=28
tm=38
x= 4*10e-2
T=24*3600
w=(2*pi)/T
D=0.75
delta=sqrt(2*D/w)
t=np.arange(0, 232920, 10*60)
temp = t0 + tm*np.exp(-x/delta)*np.cos(w*t-(x/delta))

plt.plot(t, temp, label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (c)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

I am now trying to get python to solve the code and get the same result

Comment: Could you provide a link or post in your question that equation that you are trying to solve? Are you wanting, essentially, to perform numerically integrate your variable `T` over one of its dimensions?

Comment: @MattPitkin I changed the post

Comment: Currently your `T` is a function of both time and x-position, but from the initial plot it looks like you just want it as a function of time. So, essentially, you want to integrate over the x-dimension. The simplest way to do this is just sum over the x-dimension, e.g., `plt.plot(t, np.sum(T, axis=1) * dx, label='temperature fluctuation')`. If you want a slightly more accurate integral, using the trapezium rule, you could use the NumPy [`trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) function.